# How to save iteration no. on key press in matlab

Tags: matlab, keyboard, save, iteration, figure

```
for i=1:100
      fid=loadfigure(fnames(i).name)
      pause(5)
end
```

The pause function is added to check figure. How to save iteration number (in fact, the file number) upon key press.

Comment: If the key press is ctrl+c then `i` will have the value you are looking for.

Comment: The question is how will it get stored as variable, which could be seen at the end of iteration as a set of values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`timer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) instead of [`pause`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) with Java Robot. Use [`input`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) for key presses in the command window.
`input` returns an empty matrix if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed before pressing anything else. The below code waits for the user input for 5 seconds and if the user doesn't input anything, the Java Robot will press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the code proceeds to the next iteration. If the `input` function returns something then it saves the iteration number before proceeding to the next iteration.

```
t = timer('StartDelay', 5, 'TimerFcn', @PressEnterButton);
ind=1;
for k=1:100
    fid=loadfigure(fnames(i).name);  %as it is from your code

    start(t);   %start the 5sec timer
    if ~isempty(input('Wait for button press','s'));
        iterNum{ind}= k;    ind=ind+1;
    end       
    stop(t);    %stop the timer object
end
delete(t);      %delete the timer object
```

```
function PressEnterButton(HObj, event)
%Function to press Enter button
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
r=Robot;
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
end
```

P.S: The above code saves the iteration number when ***alphanumeric and/or special character keys*** are pressed.

Comment: ind is not storing values. Some problem.

Comment: Please explain. Not working is not a  problem statement.